# poles of the rational differential form $df$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

I'm working with divisors rational differential forms $\omega\in\Omega^1_{k(C)/k}$ where $C$ is a projective (irreducible) curve over an algebraically closed field $k$. In Silverman, *The arithmetic of elliptic curves*, Proposition II.4.3(b) is written that if $f\in k(C)$ is regular at $P$ (that is $f\in\mathcal{O}_{C,P}$) then $df/dt$ is also regular at $P$ (where $t$ is an uniformiser, so I guess that $C$ is smooth).

I'm seeking for a proof of that. In Silverman is written to see in Hartshorne the comment following IV.2.1: I don't see the link. There is an other reference that I don't have (Robert, Elliptic curves, II.3.10).

Ideas:

If $f$ is regular then $f=at^n$ with $a$ locally invertible, so $df=nat^{n-1}dt+t^nda$ so $df/dt=nat^{n-1}+t^nda/dt$ so I can suppose that $f\in \mathcal{O}_{C,P}^*$. It doesn't help me.

If $f$ regular then there is an open neighborhood of $U$ of $P$ with $f\in\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ so that $df\in\Omega^1_{X/k}(U)$, so I have to prove that the $\omega\in\Omega^1_{C/k}(U)$ don't have any pole in $U$. That should be evident but how prove it?

Comment: Hartshorne IV.2.1 says $f^* dt = g du$ with $g\in \mathcal O_P$ which is exactly what you want because $f^* dt = df$ and so $g = df/du$ which you want to be in $\mathcal O_P$.

Comment: I have difficulties to understand why $f^* dt=df$: here we have $f\in\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ with $P\in U$ so we can consider that $f\in\text{Hom}(U,\mathbb{A}^1_k)$ (structuraly $f^* T=f$). With $Q=f(P)$ the morphism $f$ induces $\Omega_{\mathbb{A}^1_k/k,Q}\to\Omega_{U/k,P}$. If $t$ is the uniformizer of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^1_k,Q}$ we have $f^*dt=d(f^*t)$ but here $t\neq T$ apriori. If $Q$ is rationnal one can write $Q=(T-\alpha)$ so that $t=T-\alpha$ and then $f^*t=f-\alpha$ so $d(f^*t)=d(f-\alpha)=df$, but how proceed if $Q$ is not rationnal? Maybe it's true only for $k$algebraically closed.

Comment: I can't really follow what you're writing (what is $T$??). It seems like the only issue is picking the wrong coordinates and the possibility that the coordinate change might not be defined over a non-algebraically closed field (I am not sure this is even the case)? However, one is, by definition, working over the algebraic closure (see Silverman I.4).

Comment: Excuse me, for me $T$ is the global section of $\mathbb{A}^1_k=\text{Spec}(k[T])$.

Comment: Anyway in Hartshorne $k$ is algebraically closed, and it's the only thing I need. Thanks